# Wave Equation with Initial Data Not At t=0

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Suppose $0<s<1$ and $\phi,\psi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are $C^2$. Find a solution formula for the following boundary value problem for the wave equation in $\mathbb{R}^2$:
\begin{align}
u_{tt}&=u_{xx}, &t>sx,\\
u(x,t)&=\phi(x), &t=sx,\\
u_t(x,t)&=\psi(x),&t=sx.
\end{align}

I’ve recognized this can be solved similarly to D’Alembert’s solution, but I’m not confident how to deal with the $sx$ term. I’ve attempted to solve it following Evans 2.4.1, but have not been successful.